# Visual Studio 2012 Break points not hit

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am having an issue with Visual Studio 2012 where break points are never being hit unless I enable 
'Allow the source code to be different from the original version'

When, I do this I get a warning that the source file differs from the debug version.

I have reset the settings in visual studio and this has made no difference.  I have also created a blank project and the same thing still seems to be happening.

To try and fix this I have:

1) Rebooted the pc
2) reset all VS settings
3) Created a new blank project

Any would would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuilt the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this occur when an IIS express process gets hung up. Please close all instances of Visual Studio 2012. Then open up windows task manager and find all process that have the image name of iisexpress.exe and make sure to end those process. Then restart VS2012 and you should be good to go.